# iOS Passing function as parameter with two input

Tags: objective-c

I am still studying for passing function as parameter.

Currently, I can do like this.

```
- (void)getLocation:(void (^)(CLLocation *location))didUpdateLocation andTimeOut:(void (^)(void))timeout andDidFailUpdate:(void (^)(void))didFailUpdate
```

What I want to know is that "didUpdateLocation" can have multiple parameter? (Instead of just CLLocation *location) ? Currently,  I can't find about syntax for that.

Comment: just use like this (void (^)(CLLocation *location, NSString *param2, NSString *param3))

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a block you have defined yourself, it can have as many parameters as you want. Just add the parameter you want to the parameter list of the block like this:

```
- (void)getLocation:(void (^)(CLLocation *location, NSString *otherParameter))didUpdateLocation andTimeOut:(void (^)(void))timeout andDidFailUpdate:(void (^)(void))didFailUpdate
```